# How to override c++ string class with LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c++, function-hooking, decompile, gcc

i am trying to override predefined functions such as strcmp, getenv, etc.
i already override some of them using LD_PRELOAD options.
but i can't override string class, how can i override c++ string class

i already tried something like this;

```
class string{
    char* str;
public:
    string (char* str2){
        str = str2;
        std::cout << str2 << std::endl ;
    }
    bool operator==(char* str2)  {
        std::cout << "c++ => " << str << "==" << str2 << std::endl;
        return false; 
    }
    compare(char* str2)  {
        std::cout << "c++ => " << str << "==" << str2 << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};
```

but it doesn't work i can't print the string that compared or even defined.

compile;

```
g++ -g -Wall -shared -fPIC -ldl -o bypasscpp.so bypass.cpp
```

And running program with;

```
LD_PRELOAD="./bypasscpp.so" ./app
```

Comment: It seems you're trying to achieve something else and I feel this may not be the best way to achieve it. You may want to consider describing your end goal and look for alternative solutions.

Comment: @NirIzr i already tried many different solutions this is my last solution. I need to override these classes.

Comment: @Mustafa Adeniz Are these class methods virtual ?

Comment: @MustafaAkdeniz: seriously, Nirlzr is right. If you (also!) described what you want to achieve rather than prescribing a particular method, we would be in a better position to help. Just because this is your last straw doesn't mean there aren't better ways to achieve what you want. Why else would you be asking here?

Comment: @malikcjm thank you, this was all i need to know.

Comment: @malikcjm can you please put it in the answer box for future visitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to override `std::string`? Please check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string. `std::string` is just a `typedef` for `std::basic_string<char>` which means that `std::string` is not dynamically linked. In other words those methods you try to override are statically linked into you `./app`.

Comment: `std::string` is a name for the `char`-*specialization* of the `std::basic_string` template class. And while it can be statically linked, it is also provided as a function by the `libstdc++6.so` as evidenced by running `readelf --dyn-syms /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6|awk '$4 ~ /^FUNC/ {print $8}'|cut -d @ -f 1|c++filt|grep 'std::basic_string<char'` (tested on Ubuntu 16.04).